# How can calculating the time difference according to a condition in the table from data with the same Id

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with the same Id but no primary key. I'm trying to find the time difference from the data here. But I am having a problem, I calculate all the values with the same Id and I cannot provide the condition. To explain in more detail, if

| EventId | Active | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1 | 2022-12-20 19:07:26.6780000 |
| ABC | 0 | 2022-12-23 19:07:26.6780000 |
| ABCD | 1 | 2022-12-25 05:17:29.8480000 |
| ABCD | 0 | 2022-12-27 05:17:29.8480000 |
| ABCD | 0 | 2022-12-28 05:17:29.8480000 |

There is a table similar to this. Here, I want to calculate the time between data with the same EventId as StartTime if Active = 1, and EndTime if the first Active = 0 value. I can calculate the time.

```
SELECT [EventId], min(TimeStamp) as StartTime, max(pTimeStamp) as EndTime, DATEDIFF(hour, [TimeStamp], pTimeStamp) as TotalTime
  FROM ( select [TimeStamp], [EventId], [Active], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Active] ORDER BY ([TimeStamp])) AS number
      , LAG([TimeStamp]) OVER (PARTITION BY [EventId] ORDER BY [TimeStamp] desc) pTimeStamp
  FROM [dbo].[Event] where ([Active] = 1 or [Active] = 0)) as table
  where pTimeStamp IS NOT NULL 
 group by [EventId], [TimeStamp], pTimeStamp
```

The output of this SQL code is as follows

| EventId | StartTime | EndTime | TotalTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2022-12-20 19:07:26.6780000 | 2022-12-23 19:07:26.6780000 | 72 |
| ABCD | 2022-12-27 05:17:29.8480000 | 2022-12-28 05:17:29.8480000 | 24 |
| ABCD | 2022-12-25 05:17:29.8480000 | 2022-12-28 05:17:29.8480000 | 72 |

The query return I want is as follows: If the first Active = 1 value is StartTime, if the first Active = 0 value is EndTime, I calculate the time between. So as a table:

| EventId | StartTime | EndTime | TotalTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 2022-12-20 19:07:26.6780000 | 2022-12-23 19:07:26.6780000 | 72 |
| ABCD | 2022-12-25 05:17:29.8480000 | 2022-12-28 05:17:29.8480000 | 72 |

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You may use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
with t as
(
  select EventId,
    Min(case when Active = 1 then Timestamp end) startTime,
    Max(case when Active = 0 then Timestamp end) endTime
  from Events
  group by EventId 
)
select EventId, startTime, endTime,
       Datediff(hour, startTime, endTime) TotalTime
from t
```

Or you could do it this way:

```
select EventId,
    Min(case when Active = 1 then Timestamp end) startTime,
    Max(case when Active = 0 then Timestamp end) endTime,
    Datediff(hour,
      Min(case when Active = 1 then Timestamp end),
      Max(case when Active = 0 then Timestamp end)) TotalTime 
from Events
group by EventId
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LDdurFIn)